# Want to attach android MediaPlayer to an invisible button

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, button, android-mediaplayer

First, I created a simple program that playes media when you click on a button.

In my Main Activity class I have:

```
 MediaPlayer mySound;    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sleepnk);
    }
```

Then I created the following:

```
public void playMusic(View view)
    {
        mySound.start();
    }
```

Then in my XML file I created a button and added:

```
android:onClick="playMusic"
```

Now I am trying to add media to an app but it doesn't have something like:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        .
```

My goal is to add a media file to this "Tap to Start" invisible button in this new app but since there are no buttons in the xml file, I don't know where to attach my `playMusic` method to the Tap to Start button. I am including instances of Tap to Start button so you can see how it is acting as a button-

There is a strings.xml under values folder that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">Panoramik</string>
<string name="instruction_tap_start">Tap to start</string>
```

Then in the MainActivity.java file we have:

```
private View.OnClickListener mCameraOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mIsCapturing) {
                //clear the flag to prevent the screen of being on
                getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                if (mDMDCapture.finishShooting()) {
                    mIsStitching = true;
                    mTextViewInstruction.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                mIsCapturing = false;
                setInstructionMessage(R.string.instruction_tap_start);
```

I am also including the code for "setInstructionMessage" method:

```
private void setInstructionMessage(int msgID)
{
    if (mCurrentInstructionMessageID == msgID)
        return;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    if (msgID == R.string.instruction_empty || msgID == R.string.instruction_hold_vertically || msgID == R.string.instruction_tap_start
            || msgID == R.string.instruction_focusing) {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    } else {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    }

    mTextViewInstruction.setLayoutParams(params);
    mTextViewInstruction.setText(msgID);
    mCurrentInstructionMessageID = msgID;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can attach my media file sleepnk to the Tap to Start invisible button?

EDIT: I basically want the app to say "Tap to Start" because the app is being created for the visually impaired. So if there is any other suggestion for the app to talk back to the user, feel free to comment

Answer (score 0):

You should let the OS and TalkBack read the "android:contentDescription" attribute by assigning the string "Tap to Start" to whatever it is you want the user to touch. (Remembering to use a string resource so it can be translated/localized.)